# if multiple variables are empTY

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to check to see if any of the fields have been field out and if NONE have been field out return back to page with error. Even if I have a field filled it still returns acting like no fields are selected.

**Controller**

```
        public function getServices() {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);   

            $input = [
                    'rooms' => Input::get('rooms'),
                    'pr_deodorizer' => Input::get('pr_deodorizer'),
                    'pr_protectant' => Input::get('pr_protectant'),
                    'pr_sanitizer' => Input::get('pr_sanitizer'),
                    'fr_couch' => Input::get('fr_couch'),
                    'fr_chair' => Input::get('fr_chair'),
                    'pr_sectional' => Input::get('pr_sectional'),
                    'pr_ottoman' => Input::get('pr_ottoman'),
                    'pr_tile' => Input::get('pr_tile'),
                    'pr_hardwood' => Input::get('pr_hardwood')
            ];


            $empty = 'No services were selected';                          

            $var = $input['rooms']&& $input['pr_deodorizer']&& 
                    $input['pr_protectant']&& $input['pr_sanitizer']&&
                    $input['fr_couch']&& $input['fr_chair']&&
                    $input['pr_sectional']&& $input['pr_ottoman']&&
                    $input['pr_tiles']&& $input['pr_hardwood'];

            if(empty($var)){
                return Redirect::to('book/services')->withErrors($empty)->withInput();
            } 

            foreach($input as $services)
            {
                $service = new Service();

                $service->userID = $user->id;
                $service->services = $services;

                $service->save();
            }
            return Redirect::to('book/schedule');
    }
```

I have tried !isset() but I still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check if variable is empty, you should use `empty()` function not `&&`

when you using `&&` string "0" is casted to false, this may be not what you expecting.

if you want to detect if any of keys in array is empty use this function:

```
function arrayEmpty($keys, $array) {
    $keys = explode(" ", trim($keys));
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($array[$key]) || empty($array[$key])) return true; // isset prevents notice when $key not exists
    }
    return false;
}
```

use example:

```
$array = array( "foo" => "bar" );
arrayEmpty("foo", $array); // false
arrayEmpty("foo bar", $array); // $array["bar"] not exists, returns true
```